# Multiple outer Linq join

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application and in it I am trying pull pull a record from multiple tables by joining them. In the app I have a animal table, a birth table, and a purchase table. Every animal will have a record in the animal table but only animal bought into farm will have a record in the purchase table, same as only animals born on farm will have record in the birth table. So either the birth table or purchase table will always return a null for the query I have below:

```
    CowDetailVM animal = (from animals in db.Animals
                              join breed in db.Breeds on animals.AnimalBreed equals breed.id
                              join birth in db.Births on animals.TagNo equals birth.TagNo
                              join purchase in db.Purchases on animals.TagNo equals purchase.TagNo
                              where animals.TagNo == id && animals.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                              orderby animals.DateAdded descending

                              select new CowDetailVM
                              {
                                  TagNo = animals.TagNo,
                                  Sex = animals.Sex,
                                  AnimalBreed = breed.Breed1,
                                  DOB = animals.DOB,
                                  OwnershipStatus = animals.OwnershipStatus,
                                  BornOnFarm = animals.BornOnFarm,

                                  /*DateBought = purchase.DateBought,
                                  BoughtFrom = purchase.BoughtFrom,
                                  Price = purchase.Price,
                                  Location = purchase.Location,

                                  MotherTagNo = birth.MotherTagNo,
                                  SireTagNo = birth.SireTagNo,
                                  Difficult = birth.Difficult*/

                              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I select the data even if one table returns a null. Or it there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. Your queries translate into `INNER JOIN`s. To perform `LEFT JOIN` on `birth` and `purchase` tables you can do the following.

```
CowDetailVM animal = (from animals in db.Animals
                      join breed in db.Breeds on animals.AnimalBreed equals breed.id
                      join birth in db.Births on animals.TagNo equals birth.TagNo into j0
                      from birth in j0.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join purchase in db.Purchases on animals.TagNo equals purchase.TagNo into j1
                      from purchase in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      where animals.TagNo == id && animals.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
                      orderby animals.DateAdded descending

                      select new CowDetailVM
                      {
                          TagNo = animals.TagNo,
                          Sex = animals.Sex,
                          AnimalBreed = breed.Breed1,
                          DOB = animals.DOB,
                          OwnershipStatus = animals.OwnershipStatus,
                          BornOnFarm = animals.BornOnFarm,

                          /*DateBought = purchase.DateBought,
                          BoughtFrom = purchase.BoughtFrom,
                          Price = purchase.Price,
                          Location = purchase.Location,

                          MotherTagNo = birth.MotherTagNo,
                          SireTagNo = birth.SireTagNo,
                          Difficult = birth.Difficult*/

                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked perfect